# Dense rank for duplicated values

Tags: sql, psql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, dense-rank

```
id     val       dense_rank
1       11   =>     1
2       11          1
3       22          2
4       33          3
5       33          3
6       11          4
```

What sql should like for getting this kind of dense_rank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()` to figure out what the previous value is, then a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) filter (where prev_val is null or prev_val <> val) over (order by id) as dense_rank
from (select t.*, lag(val) over (order by id) as prev_val
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9fe603c12486bc39514d0719e5e27571) is a db<>fiddle.